MS Graph API. Copy clones 'Created' and 'Created By' attributes
I want to copy a file from one SharePoint Online folder to other.
For that i use dedicated MS Graph Copy Item API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
I see that copied file has 'Created' and 'Created By' attributes values taken from original source file.
I expect to see in 'Created By' attribute value the user who did copy and in 'Created' the date of copied file creation.
